# Compare values in a column using sql

Tags: ms-access

please help.

I have a table below.  I would like to have 2 options.

Option1: I would like to compare if values of row1 and row2 are duplicate (match), then delete row2.

Option2: if row1 and row2 in colA are duplicate, then display in column B as duplicate.  If no duplicate, then display "Go".

```
Table:

------ColA---ColB---


Row1---HBB----

Row2---HBB----


Row3---HBC----

Row4---HBD----
```

Row5---HBD----

Row6---HBD----

......

.....

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to put an expression "count if duplicate , then dup) but didn't work.

Comment: Are the values in ColA unique? Is it a primary key? If not, does the table have a primary key?

Comment: In option 2, do both rows get "DUPE"? or just row1 or just row2?  Also, in the example small set of data , if we have Row5---HBD---- then would it be a "dupe" with row4 ?  Or must we only look at odd/even pairs of row numbers?  e.g. is the following a "dupe" or not??  Row7---HBW----   and Row23---HBW----,  that is can the "dupes" be widely separated?

Comment: ColumnA is a combined of 2 number and it is unique.      In option 2, only row2 will get "DUPE". If row4, row5, row6 are the same, then "DUPE" on row5 and row6.  We only need to compare the row next to it, not to compare row5 to row23.